# Get records from a date range

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my model:

```
public class FlightSchedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "takeoff_date")
    private LocalDateTime takeoffDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("airportTakeoff")
    private Airports airportTakeoff;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("airportArrival")
    private Airports airportArrival;

}
```

This is my repository:

```
public List<FlightSchedule> findByAirportTakeoff_idAndAirportArrival_idAndTakeoffDateGreaterThanEqualAndTakeoffDateLessThan(
        String airportTakeoff, String airportArrival, LocalDateTime arrivalDate, LocalDateTime arrivalDate2);
```

And this is my service:

```
LocalDateTime takeoffLocalDate =
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(takeoffDate).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    LocalDateTime takeoffLocalDate2 =
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(takeoffDate).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime().plusDays(1);


    return flightScheduleRepository.findByAirportTakeoff_idAndAirportArrival_idAndTakeoffDateGreaterThanEqualAndTakeoffDateLessThan(
            airportTakeoff, airportArrival, takeoffLocalDate, takeoffLocalDate2)
            .stream().map(flightScheduleMapper::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

These are my records:

```
1   2019-05-28 17:00:00 TGU   MAD

6   2019-05-28 23:00:00 TGU   MAD
```

However, when make a request with:

```
/flight-schedules/optional/1558994400000/TGU/MAD

1558994400000 = 28 May 2019
```

I should get both fligths however, I get the first one. I've noticied that I don't get the flights after 21:00 hours of a day. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime.of(2019,5,28,0,0,0).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
```

This gives me a long value of `1559001600000` , which differs from your millis. So the problem is probably with your millis value, it's 3 hours different then UTC timezone.

Comment: I think it's something related with Time Zones, this is what I get when I print them out in console. this is what I get. 1559001600000 = 2019-05-28T02:00 and 1558994400000 = 2019-05-25T00:00